# How to filter include folders in Powershell while excluding others

Tags: powershell, include

I am wanting to filter through a list of folders that include a certain criteria while excluding another set of criteria in PowerShell.

The code below is what is currently being played around with that has had partial succession; `-Exclude` seems to exclude folders that contain `*EDS*` in the name but not `*eng*`. Below is a sample output of what is still being included:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Box\CTRL Active Projects\project1\project1_OPS\06-Software\04-Database Backups\01-Record Backup
C:\Users\USERNAME\Box\CTRL Active Projects\project1\project1_OPS\06-Software\04-Database Backups
C:\Users\USERNAME\Box\CTRL Active Projects\project1\project1_OPS\01-Eng\03-Submittals WIP\Backups
```

The `-Exclude *eng*, *EDS*` might eventually be converted over to a variable/named arraylist.

```
# Find sub-folder within job folder
$DatabaseFolder = (Get-ChildItem -Path $JobFolder -Filter "*Backup*" -Exclude *eng*, *EDS* -Recurse -Directory).Fullname | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime
Write-Output $DatabaseFolder
```

The `$JobFolder` returns the path to search the sub directories:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Box\CTRL Active Projects\project1\
```

Some other background info: PowerShell 5.1 is being used as Administrator, Windows 10 OS

Could someone help me understand why the code is still including some of the excluded parameters?

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. Did this just start happening? Also, when piping to your `Sort-Object`, you're not really sorting by the *LastWriteTime* property since you're only outputting the *fullname* to the pipeline.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - Three items:
(1) The issue is that it is included the 3rd full path `C:\Users\USERNAME\Box\CTRL Active Projects\project1\project1_OPS\01-Eng\03-Submittals WIP\Backups` even though the `-Exclude` is listing `*eng*, *EDS*`
(2) The other option instead of using `-Filter` was to see how `-Include` works with `-Exclude` but so far the results have been the same.
(3) The goal with `Sort-Object` was to capture and list in order an array of folders that included the the words 'backup' in the name somewhere and exclude 'EDS' and 'ENG' in its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Both `-Filter` and `-Include` / `-Exclude` only ever operate on the *last* path component - i.e. an input file-system item's *name* (`.Name` property).
- When `-Exclude` is combined with `-Recurse`, only the matching items *themselves* are excluded, *not also their subtrees*. That is, the *contents* (child items) of an excluded directory are still enumerated (unless their names too happen to match the exclusion pattern).

Therefore, `...\01-Eng\03-Submittals WIP\Backups`, for instance, was still included in your output: the `*eng*` `-Exclude` filter excluded `...\01-Eng` itself, but kept enumerating its *subdirectories*.

As of PowerShell (Core) 7.2.1, there is *no* direct way to exclude directory *subtrees* by wildcard patterns from a `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` enumeration; [GitHub issue #15159](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15159) proposes adding this functionality.

---

Therefore, you'll have to perform your exclusions by *post*-filtering with a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call that matches against the *full path* (`.FullName` property):

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path $JobFolder -Filter *Backup* |
  Where-Object FullName -notmatch 'eng|EDS'
```

Note: For brevity, `-notmatch` with a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) that uses alternation (`|`) is used to match multiple substrings.

To use [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expressions, you'd have to use the `-notlike` operator *multiple* times, once for each pattern (which would also require you to use a *script block* argument, with explicit use of `$_`, i.e. you then couldn't use the [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax) shown above; in other words:
`Where-Object { $_.FullName -notlike '*eng*' -and $_.FullName -notlike '*EDS*' }`).

Comment: mklement0, another parameter that was added to some of the folder searches were using a `-Depth` for the recursion. Even though `FullName` will have the full path searched at, could `-Depth` also be used to limit which folders are returned if character matching is known to a certain depth? i.e. `-Depth 1`.

Thank you for the response; immensely informative!

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Screamcheese; my pleasure. Yes, `-Depth` can be used to limit how many levels of the subtree hierarchy are enumerated (`0`  only enumerates immediate children, `1` also enumerates children of children, ...), and `-Filter` and `-Include` / `-Exclude` are then applied to that constrained enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the documentation about using Filter and Exclude:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2

However, since it's not working as you intended, you can always manually perform the exclude:

```
gci -recurse -directory | ? { $_.Name -notlike "*eng*" -and $_.Name -notlike "*EDS*" }
```

Comment: thepip3r, a couple things: (1) an alternative approach would be to use `-Include` with `-Exclude` somehow, (2) manually performing the exclude with your example could become a little more tedious and error prone if a list of elements/patterns needs to be updated or scalable, so another desired approach would be to having an arraylist to be a little more dynamic.